# exec function is disabled when putting website into production mode

Tags: magento2

I have my site on Magento 2.2.6
I ran command php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production to set my site in Production mode.
It throws following error
"exec function is disabled."
When I talked to my hosting provider, they say that the exec function is disabled for security reasons. I have to search for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the set command with the -s option and after that compile and deploy magento.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set {mode} [-s|--skip-compilation]

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
```